# Count of unique combinations of values in selected columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, combinations

I have a PySpark data frame that looks like this:

```
----------------------------
id    A    B    C 
id1   on   on   on
id1   on   off  on 
id1   on   on   on 
id1   on   on   on 
id1   on   on   off
-----------------------------
```

I am looking for a way to find all unique combinations for selected columns and show their count.
The expected output:

```
----------------------------
id    A    B    C    count
id1   on   on   on   3
id1   on   off  on   1
id1   on   on   off  1
-----------------------------
```

I see that there is [a way to do a similar operation in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268817/unique-combinations-of-values-in-selected-columns-in-pandas-data-frame-and-count), but I need PySpark.

UPD:
Also, please note that a unique combination of columns A and B is not the same as a combination of A,B,C. I want all possible combination of every column. Is there a way to achieve it rather than grouping by and counting one combination, another combination, etc.? There are more that 10 columns.

Comment: you can `groupBy()` on all the columns and take the count. see the following question -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/71353304/8279585

Comment: samkart, yes, I know. But count of groupby id, A, B is not the same as a count of groupby A, B, C, or A , C. Is there a way to count every possible combination of every column by one line of code?

Comment: based on your "want" example above -- a simple `groupBy()` followed by count is all you're looking for. the eqv sql would be `select id, a, b, c, count(*) as cnt from table group by 1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: I updated the description, so it explains what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[`cube`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube) can do it. But it displays ALL combinations including if some columns were not taken into account. So you will have to filter afterwards.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('id1', 'on', 'on', 'on'),
     ('id1', 'on', 'off', 'on'), 
     ('id1', 'on', 'on', 'on'), 
     ('id1', 'on', 'on', 'on'), 
     ('id1', 'on', 'on', 'off')],
    ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

df = df.cube(df.columns).count()
df = df.filter(F.forall(F.array(df.columns), lambda x: x.isNotNull()))

df.show()
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
# | id|  A|  B|  C|count|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
# |id1| on| on| on|    3|
# |id1| on|off| on|    1|
# |id1| on| on|off|    1|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
```

---

This would count occurrences just in specified columns:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B']
df = df.cube(cols).count()
df = df.filter(F.forall(F.array(df.columns), lambda x: x.isNotNull()))

df.show()
# +---+---+-----+
# |  A|  B|count|
# +---+---+-----+
# | on|off|    1|
# | on| on|    4|
# +---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("id1", "on","on","on"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        ("id1", "on","off","on"),
        ("id1", "on","on","on"),
        ("id1", "on","on","on"),
        ("id1", "on","on","off"),
    ],
    ["id", "A" , "B" , "C"]  # add your column names here
)
```

Apart from Cube function, we also have Rollup function.

**cube**: It takes a list of columns and applies aggregate expressions to all possible combinations of the grouping columns.

**rollup**: A similar function to **cube** is **rollup** which computes hierarchical subtotals from left to right.
With **GROUP BY ROLLUP(...)** is similar to CUBE but works **hierarchically** by filling columns from left to right.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.rollup(df.columns).count()

df1 = df.na.drop(subset=df.columns)

df1.show()

# ---+---+---+---+-----+
# | id|  A|  B|  C|count|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
# |id1| on| on|off|    1|
# |id1| on| on| on|    3|
# |id1| on|off| on|    1|
# +---+---+---+---+-----+
```